# Is it possible to have an array of classes in Java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to do something like this in Java?

```
class Foo { ... };
class Bar { ... };
class Baz { ... };

Object arr[] = {Foo, Bar, Baz};
```

Update:

This is what I'm trying to avoid:

```
        switch (entity) {
        case "Book":
            switch (action) {
            case "create":
                Book.create();
                break;
            case "read":
                Book.read();
                break;
            case "update":
                Book.update();
                break;
            case "destroy":
                Book.destroy();
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Author":
            switch (action) {
            case "create":
                Author.create();
                break;
            case "read":
                Author.read();
                break;
            case "update":
                Author.create();
                break;
            case "destroy":
                Author.destroy();
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Publisher":
            switch (action) {
            case "create":
                Publisher.create();
                break;
            case "read":
                Publisher.read();
                break;
            case "update":
                Publisher.update();
                break;
            case "destroy":
                Publisher.destroy();
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
```

It seems this would be very simple to do in something like Ruby:

```
my_models = [Book, Publisher, Author]

puts "choose a model"
model = # read from stdin
action = #read action from stdin
my_models[model].call_method(action)
```

I'm more used to Ruby than I am Java.

Comment: Yes, `{Foo.class, Bar.class, Baz.class}`.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Very strange to hold an array of `classes` - Are you sure you do not mean `Objects` ?

Comment: I want to be able to call static methods on those classes... sounds like this isn't possible due to strict typing.

Comment: I want the user to be able to select a number, 1-3, and then look up one of the classes in the array, and call a static method on that class. This seems like a common thing in scripting languages, although it seems this isn't possible in a compiled/strictly typed language.

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere it is possible – I posted an answer below with details

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere that sounds like a very bad solution. You don't want to use reflection unless you absolutely have to. Why not just call the static method directly depending on which number they choose?

Comment: I added some more details as to what I'm trying to do exactly... maybe the solution I'm thinking of doesn't exist in Java, but can be done a different way.

Comment: What author, book, etc are you trying to create or destroy using these static methods?

Comment: Any and all? Are you familiar with the MVC pattern? These classes that I've made are supposed to be models.

Answer (score 0):

If the methods aren't a part of a common interface, you could make an array of `Runnable` functions that wrap calls to static methods. Then just take a wrapper function out of the array and `run` it:

```
class A {
    static void someStaticMethod(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

class B {
    static void someOtherStaticMethod(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Runnable[] funcs = {() -> A.someStaticMethod(1),
                            () -> B.someOtherStaticMethod("2")};

        Runnable chosenF = funcs[1];  // Grab a method call from the array

        chosenF.run();  // And run it. Prints 2
     }
}
```

If you need the method to take or return data, you could use an [existing Functional Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) that matches what you need, or you could write your own.

Arguably this is an "abuse" of `Runnable` since `Runnable` is intended for functions to be executed in another thread. It works fine here though, and you could write your own version if need-be.

Answer (score 0):

> *I want the user to be able to select a number, 1-3, and then look up one of the classes in the array, and call a static method on that class. This seems like a common thing in scripting languages, although it seems this isn't possible in a compiled/strictly typed language.*

Yes, it is posible to run a static method on a class when all you have is the `.class`. Here is code that shows an array of `Class` objects, with just one entry, and then it calls a specific method on it. You should be able to modify this to contain however many classes you have, and call whatever method you want.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class[] classes = new Class[]{A.class};
        classes[0].getMethod("print").invoke(null); // run named method from class in array
    }
}

class A {
    public static void print() {
        System.out.println("static print() method called on: " + A.class);
    }
}
```

Here's the output when I run that locally:

```
static print() method called on: class A
```